# ImportError: cannot import name stubs for Google App Engine GAE Init Quick Start & Tutorial

Tags: python, google-app-engine, importerror

Running into this error when trying quick start "hello" on [gae-init](http://docs.gae-init.appspot.com/quickstart/)

```
ERROR    2017-10-04 21:16:02,378 wsgi.py:263] 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/anon/Desktop/Hacking/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
        handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
      File "/Users/anon/Desktop/Hacking/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 351, in __getattr__
        self._update_configs()
      File "/Users/anon/Desktop/Hacking/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 287, in _update_configs
        self._registry.initialize()
      File "/Users/anon/Desktop/Hacking/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 160, in initialize
        import_func(self._modname)
      File "/Users/anon/Desktop/Hacking/hello/main/appengine_config.py", line 17, in <module>
        from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import stubs
    ImportError: cannot import name stubs
```

I have followed all the directions for setting up requirements on gae-init...help! Same error for the tutorial on phone book.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/gae-init/gae-init/issues/713) in gae-init; the location of the stubs package has changed in recent versions of the SDK, causing the `ImportError`.

According to the [this comment](https://github.com/gae-init/gae-init/issues/713#issuecomment-332565492) on the bug report you can work around the problem by changing the import statement in `appengine_config.py` from

`from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import stubs`

to

`from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python.runtime import stubs`